# web server is unreachable : Connection refused

Tags: nginx, ipv6

I am hosting my website on Plesk with AWS EC2 Ubuntu server 18.04. All things are working correctly except IPV6. I am trying to make my website Ipv6 enabled but fail to do so.
every time it's showing error "web server is unreachable : Connection refused" but showing my "AAAA DNS record : 2a05:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx"

I am using these sites to check Ipv6.
http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php & https://ready.chair6.net/

Comment: Do you have a firewall in place and does it allow IPV6 traffic?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your apache is running on IPv4 only. A connection refused is a sign that the checked port isn't bound to any process. If you have shell access check for the Listen parameter in apache2.conf (or in the other config-file under /etc/apache2). It should look like:

```
Listen [2a05:xxxx:xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:80
```